# Does infalling material leaves a detectable imprint on the black hole's event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, accretion-disk, no-hair-theorem

An external observer will never see anything cross the event horizon, and in most explanations the story ends here.

But I wonder what happens with gravitational effects of the material?

For example super massive black holes at the center of galaxies probably earned most of their mass via accretion disks near their equator. Does that mean we can observe these mascons near their equator?

If it turns out there are no mascons, then what is the physical process that smears out the mass of the infalling material evenly along the horizon? Why doesn't the infalling observer notice this, while falling in?

Comment: what do you mean by "mascons"?

Comment: I *think* it is "mass concentration" as explained in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy). Only the OP can confirm though

Comment: @Void user1620696 is right.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer assumes that the no-hair conjecture accurately describes physical black holes.

By the no-hair conjecture, any black hole can be uniquely described by specifying three parameters: its total mass, its total angular momentum, and its total electric charge. Therefore, any detail in the event horizon must *only* depend on these three parameters. More to the point, every collection of infalling matter which influences these parameters in identical ways will leave an identical "imprint".

For example, suppose we had two collections of infalling matter: collection A is a spherical shell of matter that starts at rest, and collection B is a disc of matter that starts at rest. Both collections have the same total mass, and both are electrically neutral. Both also have zero angular momentum. Therefore, both of these configurations will increase only the total mass of the black hole, and their effect on the event horizon is indistinguishable. So no, you can't in general tell if most of the matter fell into the equator of a black hole.

The process that generates this indistinguishability is not currently known (once again, this assumes that the no-hair conjecture is accurate).

Comment: Is there a reason that you talk about the "no-hair conjecture" rather than the "no-hair theorem?" AFAIK the theorem is proved for electrovac and stationary solutions. There's a separate question of whether the result is a good approximation for an astrophysical black hole, but I think the answer is yes (except during the ring-down of a merger), and in any case that doesn't affect the validity of the theorem.

Comment: @BenCrowell Just covering my bases. From the corresponding Wikipedia article: "There is still no rigorous mathematical proof of a general no-hair theorem, and mathematicians refer to it as the no-hair conjecture. Even in the case of gravity alone (i.e., zero electric fields), the conjecture has only been partially resolved by results of Stephen Hawking, Brandon Carter, and David C. Robinson, under the additional hypothesis of non-degenerate event horizons and the technical, restrictive and difficult-to-justify assumption of real analyticity of the space-time continuum."

Comment: I wonder if an object in close orbit around a black hole would experience variations in trajectory due to shifting densities in mass. The answer would appear to be "no", but I'd really like to see an actual observation. I'm not sure if stars whipping around a black hole count. Maybe variations in an accretion disk.